# Iterative method for largest eigenvalue by imaginary/real part

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

To find the largest eigenvalue of magnitude of a general square matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ one can use the power iteration algorithm with a random inital vector $r_0\in\mathbb{C}^n$.

However ARPACK is also able to compute largest eigenvalues by either real or imaginary part (see "ARPACK USERS GUIDE: Solution of Large Scale Eigenvalue Problems by Implicitly Restarted Arnoldi Methods", p.97). Is this an advantage of the Arnoldi iteration or is it possible to achieve the same using power iteration? If it is only possible using Arnoldi iteration could you explain how this is done, i.e. where there criterion of largest real or imaginary part is enforced?